# .C & .H File Errors

Tags: c, xcode, struct, fractions

I get 18 yield sign errors & 2 stop sign errors in Xcode.
For all the 18 yield errors, they say "Using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when argument is of integer type". What does this mean? 
As for the 2 stop sign errors, they are for "_main", referenced from: **and** Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
**What do I need to do to get my script to build and run?**
H file:

```
struct fraction{
    int wholeNumber;
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

struct fraction fractionCreate(int numerator, int denominator);
struct fraction fractionAdd(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
struct fraction fractionSubtract(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
struct fraction fractionMultiply(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
struct fraction fractionDivide(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
void fractionPrint(struct fraction f);
```

C file:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fraction.h"

struct fraction fractionCreate(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    struct fraction result;
    result.wholeNumber = 0;
    if (denominator == 0)
    {
        result.numerator = 0;
        result.denominator = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (numerator*denominator <0)
        {

            int tempNumerator = fabs(numerator);
            int tempDenominator = fabs(denominator);
            int temp = 0;
            while(tempDenominator != 0)
            {
                temp = tempDenominator;
                tempDenominator = tempNumerator%tempDenominator;
                tempNumerator = temp;
            }
            int GCD = tempNumerator;

            numerator = fabs(numerator);
            denominator = fabs(denominator);
            //Num is larger than denom
            if(numerator>=denominator)
            {
                //whole number
                if(numerator%denominator == 0)
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = (numerator/denominator)*-1;
                    result.numerator = 1;
                    result.denominator = 1;
                }
                //mixed number
                else
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = ((numerator - (numerator%denominator)) /denominator)*-1;
                    numerator = (numerator%denominator);
                    if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                        result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator;
                        result.denominator = denominator;
                    }
                }
            }

            //simple fraction
            else
            {
                if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                {
                    result.numerator = (numerator/GCD)*-1;
                    result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator*-1;
                    result.denominator = denominator;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (numerator*denominator > 0)
        {
            int tempNumerator = fabs(numerator);
            int tempDenominator = fabs(denominator);
            int temp = 0;
            while(tempDenominator != 0)
            {
                temp = tempDenominator;
                tempDenominator = tempNumerator%tempDenominator;
                tempNumerator = temp;
            }
            int GCD = tempNumerator;
            numerator = fabs(numerator);
            denominator = fabs(denominator);

            //Num is larger than denom
            if(numerator>=denominator)
            {
                //whole number
                if(numerator%denominator == 0)
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = numerator/denominator;
                    result.numerator = 1;
                    result.denominator = 1;
                }
                //mixed number
                else
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = (numerator - (numerator%denominator)) /denominator;
                    numerator = (numerator%denominator);
                    if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                        result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator;
                        result.denominator = denominator;
                    }
                }
            }

            //simple fraction
            else
            {
                if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                    result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator;
                    result.denominator = denominator;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void fractionPrint(struct fraction f)
{
    if (f.numerator == 0 && f.denominator == 0)
    {
        printf("Divide by zero!\n");
    }
    else if(f.numerator ==0 && f.denominator !=0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // There IS a whole number
        if (f.wholeNumber !=0)
        {
            //ONLY whole number
            if (f.numerator == 1 && f.denominator ==1 )
            {
                printf("%d\n", f.wholeNumber);
            }
            //Mixed number
            else
            {
                printf("%d %d/%d\n", f.wholeNumber, f.numerator, f.denominator);
            }
        }
        //fraction only
        else
        {
            printf("%d/%d\n", f.numerator, f.denominator);
        }
    }

}




struct fraction fractionAdd(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;

    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;

    //If the denominators equal
    if (a.denominator == b.denominator)
    {
        result.numerator = a.numerator + b.numerator;
        result.denominator = b.denominator;
        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);
        return result;
    }
    else if (a.denominator == 0 && b.denominator == 0)
    {
    }
    //If the denominator is not equal,
    else if (a.denominator != b.denominator)
    {
        int LCM;
        int temp =0;
        //only use the absolute values when finding the GCD
        int tempDenominatorA = fabs(a.denominator);
        int tempDenominatorB = fabs(b.denominator);

        while(tempDenominatorB!=0)
        {
            temp = tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorB = tempDenominatorA%tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorA = temp;
        }
        int GCD = tempDenominatorA;
        LCM = fabs(a.denominator*b.denominator)/GCD;

        //then multiply each denominator and numerator by a number that will make it the LCM
        int multiplyA, multiplyB;
        multiplyA = LCM/fabs(a.denominator);
        multiplyB = LCM/fabs(b.denominator);
        a.numerator = a.numerator*multiplyA;
        b.numerator = b.numerator*multiplyB;

        result.numerator = a.numerator + b.numerator;
        result.denominator = LCM;

        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

        return result;

    }

    return result;
}

struct fraction fractionSubtract(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;

    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;
    a.wholeNumber = 0;
    b.wholeNumber = 0;

    //If the denominators equal
    if (a.denominator == b.denominator)
    {
        result.numerator = a.numerator - b.numerator;
        result.denominator = b.denominator;
        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);
        return result;
    }
    else if (a.denominator == 0 && b.denominator == 0)
    {
    }
    //If the denominator is not equal,
    else if (a.denominator != b.denominator)
    {
        int LCM;
        int temp =0;
        //only use the absolute values when finding the GCD
        int tempDenominatorA = fabs(a.denominator);
        int tempDenominatorB = fabs(b.denominator);

        while(tempDenominatorB!=0)
        {
            temp = tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorB = tempDenominatorA%tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorA = temp;
        }
        int GCD = tempDenominatorA;
        LCM = fabs(a.denominator*b.denominator)/GCD;

        //then multiply each denominator and numerator by a number that will make it the LCM
        int multiplyA, multiplyB;
        multiplyA = LCM/fabs(a.denominator);
        multiplyB = LCM/fabs(b.denominator);
        a.numerator = a.numerator*multiplyA;
        b.numerator = b.numerator*multiplyB;

        result.numerator = a.numerator - b.numerator;
        result.denominator = LCM;

        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

        return result;

    }

    return result;
}

struct fraction fractionMultiply(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;
    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;

    a.wholeNumber = 0;
    b.wholeNumber = 0;

    result.numerator = a.numerator*b.numerator;
    result.denominator = a.denominator*b.denominator;

    result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

    return result;
}

struct fraction fractionDivide(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;
    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;

    a.wholeNumber = 0;
    b.wholeNumber = 0;

    result.numerator = a.numerator*b.denominator;
    result.denominator = a.denominator*b.numerator;

    result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Still getting "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)." though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the fabs problem is that you are passing integers to a function that both receives and generates a floating point numbers. For example `int numerator` is being passed to and then set from the floating point return value at `numerator = fabs(numerator);` It looks like the same pattern happens enough to be 18 errors.

Perhaps you want the abs() vs. fabs() function? Abs() takes and returns ints. Or you could cast back and forth from floats to ints (ugly).

The second issue is that there is no main() function. That is where the code is going to start running and the linker is saying it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

function `fabs()` expects parameter type `double`, and requires `#include<math.h>`

> double fabs (double x);

and function `abs()`expects parameter type `int`,and requires `#include<stdlib.h>`

> int abs (int n);

- [fabs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/)

  ```
  /* fabs example */
  #include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
  #include <math.h>       /* fabs */

  int main ()
  {
    printf ("The absolute value of 3.1416 is %f\n", fabs (3.1416) );
    printf ("The absolute value of -10.6 is %f\n", fabs (-10.6) );
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- [abs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/)

  ```
  /* abs example */
  #include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
  #include <stdlib.h>     /* abs */

  int main ()
  {
     int n,m;
     n=abs(23);
     m=abs(-11);
     printf ("n=%d\n",n);
     printf ("m=%d\n",m);
     return 0;
   }
  ```